# Switch button stay with the status as a result of the query and update the database without refreshing the screen by clicking the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a grid screen that displays the return of a select, but I have 2 pieces of information that I cannot consistently display in the modem and lock column. In the database, this information comes as ON and OFF, but I did not leave the switch buttons with the value that comes from the bank, they all appear ON.
And I would also like to click on these buttons to update the database without refreshing the screen, I'm not sure if using ajax, jquery I'm using php with database in mysql.

[image]

```html
<div class="table-responsive table-responsive-data2">
  <table class="table table-data2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Local</th>
        <th>Dispositivo</th>
        <th>Serial</th>
        <th>Modem</th>
        <th>Fechadura</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
            $lista = Monitoramento::listar();
                foreach ($lista as $ordem) : ?>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="tr-shadow">

          <td class="desc">
            <?php echo $ordem['CLIENTE']; ?>
          </td>
          <td class="desc">
            <?php echo $ordem['LOCAL']; ?>
          </td>
          <td class="desc">
            <?php echo $ordem['DISPOSITIVO']; ?>
          </td>
          <td class="desc">
            <?php echo $ordem['SERIE']; ?>
          </td>
          <td> <label class="switch switch-text switch-success switch-pill">
                      <input  id="input_modem" onchange="process_led1()" type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked="true">
                      <span data-on="On" data-off="Off" class="switch-label"></span>
                      <span class="switch-handle"></span></label></td>

          <td> <label class="switch switch-text switch-success switch-pill">
                      <input  id="input_fechadura" onchange="process_led2()" type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked="true">
                      <span data-on="On" data-off="Off" class="switch-label"></span>
                      <span class="switch-handle"></span> </label></td>
```

Comment: If you make a snippet, PLEASE use HTML and JavaScript and CSS only. No PHP - it is not a PHP question anyway - we want a [mcve]

Comment: And you can certainly use Ajax with the buttons

Comment: Do you have an example? PHP is for displaying the button status using database.

Comment: `<?= $isChecked?"checked":"" ?>`